# Replacing values from one set with values from another, if the value of set1 = the key of set2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, replace, output

EDIT: Changed dictionaries to Sets, as I had not realised {} denoted a set. And fixed to say that sets are included in a tuple.

I want to iterate through each set in cardTuple, and for **each value**, **replace** it with the corresponding value(face) from **imageDict**. I assume we match value with with index, and somehow output the face. Maybe I need a third set or list to store results in before outputting?

```
imageDict = dict() # Contains index:face and looks like 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14 

cardTuple = ({7, 42, 15, 47, 20, 52, 25, 30}, {3, 39, 14, 47, 55, 22, 23, 31})
```

My current approach:

```
newList = []
newList2 = []
for i in cardTuple:
      for j in i:
           if i == 1: ## maybe this needs to be 0?
               newList.append(imageDict[j])
           elif i == 2: ##  maybe 1?
               newList2.append(imageDict[j])
```

Any advice?

Comment: Are you aware that `dict1` is not a dictionary? What is the expected output?

Comment: My advice is to take a look at [ask] and understand how to provide a [MCVE] of your last attempt.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I fixed it to reference sets instead. I'll also try to follow IdleHands and add more details in a little while, providing more snippets from my code. Thanks!

Comment: If you use sets, the order of result might change as sets are unordered. I believe that's fine.

Comment: The order need not matter, thankfully. If so I maybe would have stuck to lists or tuples.

Comment: @Karim: To be clear, the meaning of curly braces (`{}`) depends on their content. If they're empty, or they store key-value pairs separated by colons (`:`), they're a `dict`. If they're non-empty, but don't have a colon in them, they're a `set`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That makes things much clearer. Thank you.

Comment: You have many items that don't have entry in `imageDict`. What about them?

Comment: @Karim Is the given answer any help?

Comment: @Austin - In fact, my faces dictionary goes up to 57.

Comment: @berkelem I haven't attempted your solution yet. Could you possibly briefly walk me through how your output variable functions?

Comment: Must cardTuple be a `tuple` of `set`s? Can they not be `list`s? It's much more trivial to replace items within a `list` than it is to a `set`.

Comment: Well, cardTuple is a random sample generated from a dictionary of valid cards. I wonder if I could convert them back to a list by doing something like list().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as mentioned in the comments, `dict1` is not a dict. It is a `set`. But you probably meant for it to be a `list`.
Here's a simple way to get what you want using list comprehensions:

```
mylist = [1,5,7,10,13]
mydict = {
          1:face1,2:face2,3:face3,4:face4,5:face5,6:face6,7:face7,
          8:face8,9:face9,10:face10,11:face11,12:face12,13:face13
         }

output = [mydict[key] for key in mylist]

>>> [face1, face5, face7, face10, face13]
```

Comment: So with output, you're creating a new list but I don't understand how the comparison works with "for key in mylist". Maybe you could explain what mydict[key] is doing? Is it comparing mydict key with key in mylist? If so, is it automatic that it outputs the value?

Comment: `mydict[key]` is extracting the value (`face1`,`face2`...) based on the `key` provided.  In this case, the item in `mylist`.  In this example it's essentially creating a list of `mydict[1], mydict[5], mydict[7]...` based on `mylist = [1,5,7...]`

Comment: `dict` objects are a collection of `key: value` pairs. By saying `mydict[key]` I am accessing the `value` associated with that `key`. By doing this in a for loop in a list comprehension, I am creating an output `list` type where each entry is the `value` associated with each `key` in `mylist`. 
You might want to look up list comprehensions - they are very useful Python constructions.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated for the explanation. I'm going to try this solution than what I was working on now.

Comment: If this answered your question feel free to accept the answer :)